# Multiple iframes on one site, only first 2 loads

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have 4 iframes on my website

```html
<iframe src="http://google.com"></iframe><p></p>
<iframe src="http://yahoo.com"></iframe><p></p>
<iframe src="http://ask.com"></iframe><p></p>
<iframe src="http://bing.com"></iframe><p></p>
```

but only 2 iframes loads, how can i make all of them load ?

Answer (score 1):

Some of the websites do not allow to load them inside `<iframe>`'s. This is connected to security issues especially clickjacking. If you will open devtools console you will probably see errors like this:

> Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

or like this:

> Refused to display 'https://www.ask.com/' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'none'".

You can't do anything about it except this pages are owned by you so you can modify `X-Frame-Options` HTTP header.